# Element blocker for Google Chrome?

Tags: chrome, website-blocker

I'm looking for a Google Chrome extension that allows me to select certain elements on a webpage and block them.

I'd like it to block intrusive ads on webpages that make me disable my adblocker, as well as remove distracting parts of webpages that aren't ads.

Requirements:

- Must not trigger "disable adblock" warnings unless I block an element that causes that popup to appear.
- Must be able to block selected element until I remove it from the list.

The closest extension I've found was [HTML Content Blocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html-content-blocker/nobnkgabkebhhlgfddbemmefjnjnahoe?hl=en-US), but it only blocks **all** HTML tags for what you select - not certain ones.

Is there an extension that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a tool that can overwrite the CSS of the pages. For example Stylebot. Then you could simply hide elements by setting "display" to "none".

> Stylebot lets you manipulate the appearance of any website with custom CSS.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha

Comment: It works! The "Open Stylebot" button in its extension menu didn't work, but right click element > Stylebot > Style Element > Layout and Visibility > Hide did.